# Builder with generics

Tags: java, oop, generics, design-patterns, builder

I have the following hierarchy

A doubly generic class named

```
public class Service<T, U> 
{
    private final Supplier<T>
    private final Function<T, U>
    private final Consumer<U>
    // more fields and methods ...
}
```

A Builder for that class `ServiceBuilder<T, U>` with the usual fluent API for builder

```
public class ServiceBuilder<T, U>
{
    private Supplier<T> supplier;
    private Function<T, U> mapper;
    private Consumer<U> consumer;
    // more fields and methods ....

    public ServiceBuilder<T, U> withSupplier(Supplier<T> supplier)
    {
        this.supplier = supplier;
        return this;
    }

    // more fields and methods ....

    public Service<T, U> build()
    {
        return new Service(supplier, mapper, consumer);
    }
}
```

Based on this, I want to provide an easy to use Supplier of T, let's say DummySupplier

```
public class DummySupplier implements Supplier<SomeObject>
{
    public SomeObject get()
    {
        return new SomeObject();
    }
}
```

*And I want a `ServiceBuilder<SomeObject, T>` that makes use of this supplier, effectively fixing `T` so that I only need a `Function<SomeObject, U> mapper` and a `Consumer<U> consumer>` to build my service.*

How may I approach this? Extending `ServiceBuilder` does not work because all its existing methods that I want to reuse return `ServiceBuilder` and not some class extending `ServiceBuilder` ...

Is there some known pattern to approach?

Comment: the return value could be `? extends ServiceBuilder`

Comment: With that return value does not compile `public <V extends Service<T, U>> V build()
    {
        return new Service<>(supplier, mapper, consumer);
    }`

Comment: Why do you want a new specified class anyway? The normal `ServiceBuilder` should be fine, you can just override the initial `Supplier<SomeObject>` again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither `Function<SomeObject, U> mapper` nor `SomeObject` know the `DummySupplier`. 
This information must be placed somewhere, for example in a `SpecializedServiceBuilder`:

```java
public class SpecializedServiceBuilder<U> extends ServiceBuilder<SomeObject, U> {

    ServiceBuilder withSomeObjectFunction(Function<SomeObject, U> mapper) {
        this.supplier = new DummySupplier();
        this.mapper = mapper;
        return this;
    }
}
```

Comment: That `SpecializedServiceBuilder` leaves `T` unespecified, and it should be `SomeObject`

Comment: shouldn't it be `public class SpecializedServiceBuilder<U> extends ServiceBuilder<SomeObject,U>` ?

Comment: @kutschkem you are right, I fixed my answer, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why you need a specified subclass, you can just create a factory method giving you a standard `ServiceBuilder<SomeClass, U>`.

```
public static <U> ServiceBuilder<SomeClass, U> withDummyBuilder() {
    return new ServiceBuilder<SomeClass, U>().withSupplier(SomeClass::new);
}
```

You can then call `withSupplier` again and override the `new SomeClass()` supplier, but I don't see why that's a problem.